# Laravel RESTful API Resolve Foreign Keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I'm building a RESTful API in Laravel.  So far I have a simpler controller that looks like this:

```
class TripController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $data = Trip::all();

    return $data;
  }
}
```

And I get this back:

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "created_at": "2015-07-06 21:01:03",
  "updated_at": "2015-07-06 21:01:03",
  "created_by": 1,
  "updated_by": 1,
  "description": "Sample Trip",
  "aircraft_id": 1
  }
]
```

Which is exactly what I asked for. The thing is 'created_by', 'updated_by', and 'aircraft_id' are foreign keys. I know I could start resolving my foreign keys using the relationships I've set up in my models, such as:

```
$createdByName = App\Trip::first()->createdBy()->get('name');
```

But this would require some looping over the collection to replace the id's with the information needed from the foreign keys (basically the names).  Is there a clever way to do this in Laravel when just using it to return JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declared the relations on the model via eloquent you could just use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to deliver the related models.

```
Trip::with('aircraft','createdBy','updatedBy')->all();
```

Otherwise, if you only want to include something like the name attribute you could add an attribute to your Trip model using laravels [accessor methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) 
Define an accessor like this:

```
public function getAircraftNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->aircraft->name;
}
```

And include it in the models array- or json-form by adding it to the $appends array:

```
protected $appends = ['aircraft_name'];
```

See the documentation for that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).